# check_parity + are_reversed funcions

Tags: python

I have the following task. In the solutions.py file, define two functions:

1. The check_parity function that takes two arguments - a list of numbers and a true or false value, and returns the result of the check (true or false):
   a) if the second argument is true, check if all elements of the given list are odd,
   a) if the second argument is false, check if all elements of the given list are even.
2. The are_reversed function takes two list arguments and returns true or false depending on whether the second list is equal to the first list in reverse order.

---

If the solutions are correct, running main.py should result in "All tests passed!"

Any idea how to fix this error?
My error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    assert check_parity([1, 2, 3], True) == False
AssertionError
```

```
main.py
from solutions import check_parity, are_reversed
assert check_parity([1, 2, 3], True) == False
assert check_parity([1, 2, 3], False) == False
assert check_parity([0, 2, -4], True) == False
assert check_parity([0, 2, -4], False) == True
assert check_parity([1, 3, -7], True) == True
assert check_parity([1, 3, -7], False) == False
assert are_reversed([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]) == True
assert are_reversed([1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 2]) == False
assert are_reversed([1], [1]) == True
assert are_reversed([], []) == True
assert are_reversed([1, 2, 3], [3]) == False  # na szóstkę
print('All tests passed!')

solutions.py
def check_parity(list, odd):
  pass

def are_reversed(list1, list2):
  pass
```

Answer (score 0):

The AssertionError exception occurs because the *check_parity()* function does not return False for the arguments of [1,2,3],True. Your implementation (such as it is) returns None